# Cassandra Data Read Speed Slows Down

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-python-driver

I have a problem that I can't understand. I have **3 node (RF:3)** in my cluster and my nodes hardware is pretty good. Now there are **60 - 70 million rows and 3000 columns data** in my cluster so i want to query specific data approximately **265000 rows and 4 columns**, i use default fetch size, **I can get 5000 lines of data per second up to 55000 lines of data** after that my data retrieval speed drops.

I think this situation will be solved from the cassandra.yaml file, do you have any idea what I can check?

Comment: You'll need to provide a bit more info. A friendly note on how to ask good questions. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) minimal sample code that replicates the problem. Cheers!

Comment: “I think this situation will be solved from the cassandra.yaml file“   I doubt it.  Usually this happens because partitions are too big or the query is trying to pull too much data back at once.  Have a look at this table using `nodetool tablehistograms`.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your comment, I checked that and there was a no latency about that but too big partition size for example max value 53142810146 bytes is it problem ?